# XSL 1.0 method to match messages containing text

Tags: xml, xslt, contains

I have some xml that  I want to match using xslt 1.0:

The XML is as follows (multiple lines of this throughout the xml at different levels):

```
<message level="Info">
    <![CDATA[progress-update merp]]>
</message>
<message level="Info">
    <![CDATA[Some other data]]>
</message>
```

I only want to match and select text for messages that contain the string 'progress-update'. So desired output is

progress-update merp

I tried the following but it did not work...

```
<xsl:template match="message">
    <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()[contains(text(),'progress-update')]" />
    </span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

I also tried:

```
<xsl:template match="message[contains(text(),'progress-update')]">
    <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        <br />
    </span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

but I seem to get some messages text that does not contain progress-update still and the output is not concatenated. Perhaps that is becasue it is not matched by the above? How do I block all the other lines from being matched.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Got it I think. I just needed to add another match for "message" below that block to match all the other messages and do nothing with them.